# Import NCover or Instrumentation .Coverage files back into TFS 2010. so it shows up in the build summary report

Tags: tfs, nunit, mstest, code-coverage, ncover

My project has their tests using the NUnit framework, specifically 2.5.9.  My build process currently creates nunit xml files, and then I convert them into .trx and publish them into TFS using mstest.exe.  Now, I need to report back code coverage to TFS and show up in the build summary reports.  I can create NCover results to xml, and was hoping I could include the NCover results into the NUnit xml and then convert it into the .TRX format and then import to TFS, but that's not going to work.  But, it does look like the .TRX file can accept some code coverage information, according to the vsts.xsd, but I'm not sure if it is a file reference or other metrics.

I can also create .Coverage result files using Visual Instrumentation using an example from here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/c7cd8dab-fed9-4fc4-9773-bdb047ad5958

So, I know I can publish unit test to TFS.  The question is can I publish ncover or .coverage results BACK to TFS 2010?